# Artisan shell executes too much time. How to fix?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-artisan

I have 2 laravel apps.
On typing: "time php artisan" in first app, I see:

```
real    0m0.328s
user    0m0.123s
sys     0m0.057s
```

And if type the same at my "problem" project, I see:

```
real    1m15.887s
user    0m0.220s
sys     0m0.085s
```

I try to:

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
php artisan debugbar:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

composer said, that I have

```
laravel/framework                     v5.6.26 The Laravel Framework.
```

I try to drop "`vendor`" directory, and to run `composer install` command
it also doesn't helps. What should i do to fix so long time execution? php v 7.1.4

Few hours ago everything was ok! I was working only with controllers, (no any new artisan commands was made before bug shows)
~75sec for blank artisan coomand execution to show only commands list is too much...

I realy appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: btw, "laravel.log" (~40mb) was also removed, and executed "composer cacheclear". 
Still no changes on execution time

Comment: Do you have any database queries or other heavy calculations in any of your provider classes or route files for the slow project?

Comment: No i don't have. Only in seed files and inside artisan commands (some seeds and commands have heavy code for long execution time, but it should never be a problem to parse only command signature and return it back into CLI without execution)

Comment: for example "time php artisan db:seed --class=SomeDataImporterSeeder" shows ~15 sec. as usual.
But "time php artisan" ~1m15s

Comment: Does the slow version use the laravel-debugbar and the other one not?

Comment: both projects are using debug bar, and both doesn't handle console commands, only http requests